# How can I return string array in solidity?

Tags: arrays, string, abiencoderv2

This is my struct:

```js
    struct Token {
        address tokenAddress;
        uint256 minAmount;
        bool emergencyUnlock;
        TokenStatus status;
        string name;
        uint256 decimal;
        string thumbnailUrl;
    }
```

and a mapping:

```js
    mapping(address => Token) private _token;
```

A function returns details of the token when I asked given the indexes:

```js
    function getTokens(uint256 start, uint256 length) external view returns(
        address[] memory tokenAddresses,
        uint256[] memory decimals,
        string[] memory name
    )
    {
        tokenAddresses = new address[](length);
        name = new string[](length);
        decimals = new uint256[](length);

        require(start.add(length) <= _tokens.length, "Lock: Invalid input");
        require(length > 0 && length <= 15, "Lock: Invalid length");
        uint256 count = 0;
        for(uint256 i = start; i < start.add(length); i++) {
            tokenAddresses[count] = _tokens[i].tokenAddress;
            count = count.add(1);
            decimals[count] = _tokens[i].decimal;
            name[count] = _tokens[i].name;
        }
        return(
            tokenAddresses,
            decimals,
            name
        );
    }
```

Now, the problem is that, it asks me that it is not supported to return array of string.
Error is below:

**TypeError: This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder. Use "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" to enable the feature.
string[] memory name**

Does anyone know the work around?
I know that name will not be more than 20 characters long ever.

Comment: The workaround is to `Use "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" to enable the feature. string[] memory name`!

Comment: but experimental ABIEncoderV2 is not recommended for live deployment

Comment: And so there is no way for you to return an array of strings. Perhaps on solc 0.6, but I doubt it.

Comment: @FarihaAbbasi It's not experimental anymore: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.9/layout-of-source-files.html?highlight=experimental#abiencoderv2: 'we kept the same pragma, even though it is not considered experimental anymore'.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to your query is:
Rather than including the name of the array in the return parameter. Only write "array_type []"
And if it is a string array then,
"array_type [] memory"

This Modified Code should work fine in returning the items that you want...

```js
struct Token {
    address tokenAddress;
    uint256 minAmount;
    bool emergencyUnlock;
    TokenStatus status;
    string name;
    uint256 decimal;
    string thumbnailUrl;
}
```

and a mapping:

```js
mapping(address => Token) private _token;
```

A function returns details of the token when I asked given the indexes:

```js
function getTokens(uint256 start, uint256 length) external view returns(
    address[] memory,
    uint256[] memory,
    string[] memory
)
{
    tokenAddresses = new address[](length);
    name = new string[](length);
    decimals = new uint256[](length);

    require(start.add(length) <= _tokens.length, "Lock: Invalid input");
    require(length > 0 && length <= 15, "Lock: Invalid length");
    uint256 count = 0;
    for(uint256 i = start; i < start.add(length); i++) {
        tokenAddresses[count] = _tokens[i].tokenAddress;
        count = count.add(1);
        decimals[count] = _tokens[i].decimal;
        name[count] = _tokens[i].name;
    }
    return(
        tokenAddresses,
        decimals,
        name
    );
}
```